# AngularStrap close modal with controller

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, angular-strap

I'm using AngularStrap with bootstrap.

I have a modal dialog that uses it's own controller. How can I close the modal using this local controller?

I instantiate the controller on a button like this:

```
<button type="button" 
  class="btn btn-success btn-lg" 
  bs-modal="modal" 
  data-template="user-login-modal.html"
  data-container="body"
  ng-controller="userLoginController"
  >Click here to log in</button>
```

and the userLoginController has this:

```
$scope.authenticate = function(){
    this.hide(); // this doesn't work
    }
```

This is obviously just a demo, I want it to close on successful login, but this is where the code I'd use to close it would go.

I've tried instantiating the modal programmatically (use the $modal service to create the modal) but I haven't been able to figure out how to inject the controller through that method.

If I were to do something like emit an event from the modal using the bs-modal directive, how can I reference the modal to close it?

here's my plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/m5gT1HiOl1X9poicWIEi?p=preview

Comment: Did you try `$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');`?  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: @FooL I'm not using angular-ui I'm using angularstrap http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/

Comment: I see. Haven't used it before, but it looks like you need to set up a variable with the `$modal` then you can call the `.hide()` on the new variable

Comment: @FooL If I do that then I can't use a separate controller.  Maybe I'll try merging the two adapters and use Angular-UI's modal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured out a good method:

I moved the ng-controller to the TEMPLATE and instantiate the modal using the provided modal service.  I then use a rootscope broad cast to let everyone know that someone successfully logged in.

new controller code:

```
var loginModal = $modal({template:'/template.html', show:false});

$scope.showLogin = function(){
    loginModal.$promise.then(loginModal.show);
}

$scope.$on("login", function(){
    loginModal.$promise.then(loginModal.hide);
});
```

the button just looks like this now:

```
<button type="button" 
  class="btn btn-success btn-lg" 
  ng-click="showLogin()"
  >Click here to log in</button>
```

and my template has the old ng-controller in the first tag.

Comment: I have not tried it yet but do you think passing $scope into $modal and first putting $modal on scope `$scope.$modal = $modal`. Then would your new controller have access to $modal?

Comment: But that would require the parent controlle to use $scope. Today we mostly use controllerAs, so what to do? Really necessary to inject $scope/$rootScope, and then create a new scope??

Comment: I haven't touched on this in a while, I'll have to look at it again.

Answer (score 8):

When in the on-click function do

```
$scope.myClickEvent = function () {
   this.$hide();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I am probably too late, but just wish to share my answer. If all you need is hiding the modal after form success, then bind that $hide function to one of controller varriable.

```
<div class="modal" data-ng-controller="Controller" data-ng-init="bindHideModalFunction($hide)">
```

In the controller:

```
// Bind the hiding modal function to controller and call it when form is success
$scope.hideModal;
$scope.bindHideModalFunction =function(hideModalFunction){
    $scope.hideModal = hideModalFunction;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found all of the above answers way too complicated for your use case (and mine when I ran into this problem).

All you need to do, is chain the ng-click to use the built in `$hide()` function that angular strap bundles.

So your ng-click would look like: `ng-click="authenticate();$hide()"`

Comment: not a smart idea if you want to do something that listen to the onhide. Especially with a database. The function autentication can still run and will intervere with the onhide listener

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular and bootstrap if you want to submit data to controller then have the modal close just simply add `onclick="$('.modal').modal('hide')"` line to the submit button. This way it will hit the controller and close the modal. If you use `data-dismiss="modal"` in the button submit never hits the controller. At least for me it didn't. And this is not to say my method is a best practice but a quick one liner to get data to at least submit and close out the modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" ng-controller="SubmitCtrl">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form ng-submit="submit()">
          <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
          <button type="submit" onclick="$('.modal').modal('hide')">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps open it with the service on click and have it close itself on the `$destroy` event?

```
$scope.openModal = function()
{
    $scope.modal = $modal({
        template: "user-login-modal.html",
        container="body"
    });
}

$scope.$on("$destroy", function()
{
    if ($scope.modal)
    {
        $scope.modal.hide();
    }
});
```